# Login as Member not working

Tags: members

Since updating to v2.6.1 I am no longer able to login as another member.  If I log in as a Super Admin and search for a user I can still click on the "Login as Member" link.  I am taken to the next screen and offered radio buttons, which I select "Control Panel".  It now ask for "You must submit your current Super Admin password to continue" which I provide and then I go to the main login screen.  Anyone else having this issue?  Hard to troubleshoot user issues without being able to login as the user occasionally.

Thanks!

Guy

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and was hoping to find a solution when I ran across this thread.

Comment: I can confirm this also happens for me on v2.6.1. The user I'm trying to log in with does indeed have access to the control panel and can log in directly. Anyone have any luck resolving this, aside from upgrading to a more recent version of EE? Cheers, Chris

Comment: The fix is in the new releases. You'll have to upgrade.

Comment: Having this issue also in 2.8.1 so not sure it's fixed. Anyone still having the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The radio buttons I get are

- Site Homepage
- Other

Followed by a text box to enter the URL for the "Other" location to be redirected to.
I'm then redirected to the desired location.
Maybe there is something strange in the choice of radio buttons you have?

Comment: Dorothy does the user you are attempting to log in as have access to the control panel?  Can you log in as them and access it?

Answer (score 1):

Not a technical solution, but I've found that if I don't select either of the radio buttons I'm able to login as the user (redirected to the homepage as them).

Hope this helps,
Paul